# C# UDPClient - Sending and Receiving to a program on local machine

Tags: c#, udp

I have two third party programs running on my PC which communicate with each other via UDP. Program A is simply a user-interface application which connects via UDP and allows the user to send specific hex commands to program B which sends back some acknowledgement in hex. I know that program B receives on port 11001 and sends on port 11000. I am trying to recreate program A myself in C# as a console application to start with. I've written the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            network udpNetwork = new network();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            udpNetwork.StartListener();
        }
    }

    class network
    {
        private const int sendPort = 11001; //Port to transmit to
        private const int receivePort = 11000; //Port to receive on

        public void StartListener()
        {
            string IP_Address = Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName).AddressList[1].ToString();
            IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse(IP_Address); //create IP address
            IPEndPoint endpointSend = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, sendPort);
            IPEndPoint endpointReceive = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, receivePort);

            UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            udpServer.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            udpServer.Client.Bind(endpointSend);

            var packetData = new byte[] { 0x1F, 0x7F, 0x80, 0x1F, 0xFF };
            
            try
            {
                udpServer.Connect(endpointSend);
                udpServer.Send(packetData, packetData.Length);
                udpServer.Close();

                UdpClient udpReceive = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
                udpReceive.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                udpReceive.Client.Bind(endpointReceive);
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpReceive.Receive(ref endpointReceive);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " +
                                          returnData.ToString());
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs fine until the line `Byte[] receiveBytes = udpReceive.Receive(ref endpointReceive);` where it hangs. I read that this function is blocking which means that the program is waiting for data but obviously not receiving any. Program B listening on port 11001 should send back a response after I have sent the packetData but doesn't. I don't have anyway to use program B to confirm that it is getting the data I am sending. How could I confirm that Program B receives my data in the first place, or do I have some other issue with my code?

edit:

I have edited my code to make use of IPV4 rather than IPV6 as per Jdweng's suggestion. (Shown corrected in the code snippet above). Program B is however still not receiving any data which I can confirm by using TCPView. After launchign the program from within Visual Studio 2019 TCPView shows that there were no received packets by Program B.

Comment: You are using Blocking method (Synchronous) which will wait until data is received.  So you are not receiving any data. You should be using IPV4 (not IPV6) : AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6.  Also index zero is IPV6 and you should use index one for IPV4 : AddressList[1]

Comment: @jdweng Okay, have edited the code to make use of IPV4. I used TCPview to check if program B is receiving any packets but it is still not.

Comment: What is the IP address (multicast 224 to 239)?  Are you send Broadcast or regular UDP.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if you are sending messages correctly.   Then after you get the send working then try receive.

Comment: If i run `ipconfig/all` the IPv4 address is 192.168.11.113 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. I am sending broadcast UDP - once I have something basic working I want to be able to send data when a button is clicked.

Comment: So it is not multicast.  The broadcast address is then 192.169.11.255.  Are you seeing receive messages using sniffer.  The broadcast IP is the address 255 of the subnet. 
 Otherwise it is not broadcast.

Comment: Apologies, very new to this so I didn't know what multicast was. I used wiresniffer and saw that the IP address being used by the two programs was 127.0.0.1. Changing the IPaddress to this and removing the setSocketOptions and Bind lines fixes it. Program B is now receiving packets from my console application and sends back packet data.